# Telegram Bots invitation links analysis (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I got a Telegram Bot programmed in nodeJS. I've been wondering how can I make custom links for the bot start and then be able to analyze amount of clicks/start buttons pressed through that link.

> I searched the whole internet for it and found nothing. While many many bots are there with the functionality to count every start with dynamic links generated for each user.